# Saving button value in view of viewpager

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

The way I have it laid out now:

I have a view where the user can pick a value from a radio button and click on next to view the next value. The user clicks all the way to the last page which has a save button that is supposed to get all the button values from all the pages and saves them inside the database. I am wondering, how can I save all the previous and current button values from the views in a viewpager?

I have created a map to store the values of each page and buttonValue.

```
            final HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
            int pagePosition = position;
            int buttonSelected = buttonValue;
            map.put(pagePosition, buttonSelected);

            for (Integer key : map.keySet()){
                //key is the page #
                for (Map.Entry entry : map.entrySet())
                    System.out.printf("%s, %s;", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

            }
```

The problem I am having now is where to place this code inside the viewPager. Currently, I have it inside my InstantiateItem() method but the position of the page is incorrect.

It currently displays something like this when I'm on a single page and I clicked on the third button.

```
 0, 0;1, 0;2, 0;
```

Where I have three pages in my viewpager.

How do I go back setting this up so that I click on a button and save that button to my map with the correct position and then swipe to next page, click on a button and save that button value with the correct position of the pager, etc.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **ViewPager.onPageChangeListener** like this:

```
final HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
int pagePosition;

viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        pagePosition = position;
    }
});

Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonId);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        map.put(pagePosition, buttonSelected);
    }
});
```

Adapt it to your logic.
__________________________________________________________________ 
You can do the same in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button android:id="@+id/button_1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button 1"
    android:onClick="onClick" />
```

and include this method to your activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_1:
            map.put(pagePosition, 1);
            break;
        case R.id.button_2:
            map.put(pagePosition, 2);
            break;
    }

}
```

__________________________________________________________________ 
Or you can make ViewPager send events to your activity:

```
pager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
pager.setAdapter(new SampleAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));
pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
    // no code here
}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
    // no code here
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    pagePosition = position;
}
```

[ViewPager.onPageChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html)

Comment: What do you mean by adapt it? Thanks.

Comment: I mean you have to include it in your code and test if it does what you expected.

Comment: But I have a question, the buttonValue would be nothing when the page initially loads, so I would not be able to get the buttonSelected value for the first page?

Comment: I edited the code. Now you should understand ho to implement it.

Comment: Okay gotcha. I followed your first approach. Now I just have to figure out how to retrieve values from map and save to sqlite db appropriately. Thanks. I am wondering through how can I loop through the map and get the button Value(s), so that I can save in db column?

Comment: I will not answer this here because it will become a too difficult question. You can follow this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/ or just ask another question.

Comment: Actually, figured it out. Can I update my question? I have a problem with the way I have it set now. The problem is it's doubling the times I want to save the values. So, if I have two pages and two button values, it saves it in my db as 4 pages and 4 button values. Repeating the two values. Might be a loop problem. Thank you! :D

Comment: D'oh. figured it out. fixed it. THanks!! :D